# Android: Finding a view by Id without clicking on UI button

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, view

New to Android programming, please bear with me.

I am trying to open a settings activity (using Shared Preferences) and populate it with `Checkboxes` that are set or not set depending on the current settings in the main activity.

I have managed to get it working as long as I put a button on my **Settings Activity** UI that calls the method to show the status of the `Checkboxes` as they currently are.

If I try to call the **"settingsLoadSavedSettings"** method automatically from the `onCreate` method it won't let me pass the `(View view)` parameters and without the parameters the app crashes as soon as it tries to run the `.isChecked(true)` line of code, I think because it can't find the `Checkbox` by Id without the parameters.

If I comment out the `.isChecked(true)` lines the program works correctly as far as the **Shared Preferenences** are being updated and the main app activity responds correctly if I click the checkboxes, but the `Checkboxes` come up on the Settings UI all unchecked irregardless of the main app settings at start up.

I have it working correctly except that I have to click the "Show Current Settings" button on my Settings UI after the activity loads to show the current state of the Checkboxes. I am trying to populate the Checkboxes status automatically as soon as the activity screen opens.

I left the commented out call in the `onCreate` method but I can't put `View` view in as parameters without an error **"Cannot resolve symbol 'view'".**  Again, the **settingsLoadSavedSettings** method works when called by a button on the settings activity UI and without the View view parameters the app crashes when I try to open the settings activity.

Thank you very much for any help you can offer. I'm hoping this is a simple case of my not understanding Object Oriented Programming and making a bonehead error.  I've tried searching for this, but I think that the problem is so generic that my search terms are giving me a huge range of answers

Portion of the code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
CheckBox AllowAddition, AllowSubtraction, AllowMultiplication, AllowDivision;
boolean settingAddition, settingSubtraction, settingMultipliation, settingDivision;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    //settingsLoadSavedSettings(View view);
}
public void settingsLoadSavedSettings(View view){
    AllowAddition = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.allowAddition);
    AllowSubtraction = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.allowSubtraction);
    AllowMultiplication = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.allowMultiplication);
    AllowDivision = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.allowDivision);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    settingAddition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Allow_Addition",true);
    settingSubtraction = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Allow_Subtraction",true);
    settingMultipliation = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Allow_Multiplication",true);
    settingDivision = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Allow_Division",true);
    if (settingAddition){
        AllowAddition.setChecked(true);
    }
    if (settingSubtraction){
        AllowSubtraction.setChecked(true);
       }
    if (settingMultipliation){
        AllowMultiplication.setChecked(true);
    }
    if (settingDivision){
        AllowDivision.setChecked(true);
    }

}
```

Error Log when Settings Activity Activated with Method call in onCreate:

```
02-18 20:55:13.916  24918-24918/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{com.example.mathhelper/com.example.mathhelper.SettingsActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

Comment: Make your question simple to understand by keeping description small and understandable.

Comment: I don't see you using the view parameter anywhere, so why should this have to do something with the crash? Also, posting the crash log is mandatory.

Comment: Added Crash log (null pointer Exception).

Comment: Question is:  Why do the check boxes update properly when called from a button on the UI, but crash the app when the same method is called at the end of the onCreate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The problem was that I was calling the .setChecked method before the onCreate was finished which lead to the null pointer error.  By adding the method call to a new onStart function, the checkbox is now available to be set.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    settingsLoadSavedSettings();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way harder than it needs to be-  look up [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), which does this for you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me, I hadn't stumbled into this and it would likely have saved me some grief.